# c# why can't I use else here?

Tags: c#

Basically it tells me that tal2--; else tal1 = 56; it's an error "invalid expression of else", how come?

Cheers.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int tal1, tal2;
        int slinga;

            tal2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (slinga = 0; slinga < 2; slinga++)
        {
            if (tal1 == 56)
                Console.WriteLine(Addera(slinga, tal1));
            tal2--;
            else tal1 = 56;

        }
    }
    static int Addera(int tal1, int tal2)
    {
        return tal1 + tal2;
    }
}
```

Comment: tal1 is never set to anything, so it fails here if (tal1 == 56)

Comment: @JAT look at his code and you will see that it fails because he's not wrapping the necessary code around what is called a code block `{ }` more than one statement being executed, needs to be wrapped around curly braces

Comment: @MethodMan I know, I'm not blind. But still after putting the {}, you will get an `Use of unassigned local variable 'tal1' exception in that line

Comment: true because local variables in good practiced should be initialized I agree with you..

Comment: I know that... either way I think that you understand what I am saying just as I understand what you are saying... lol cheers..it's not worth going around circles on this one..

Comment: How do I set tal1 to something?

Answer (score 3):

If "if clause" has to span more than one lines of code you have to surround it with curly brackets "{}". Change your code to :

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int tal1, tal2;
        int slinga;

        tal2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (slinga = 0; slinga < 2; slinga++)
        {
            if (tal1 == 56)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Addera(slinga, tal1));
                tal2--;
            }
            else
                tal1 = 56;
        }
    }
    static int Addera(int tal1, int tal2)
    {
        return tal1 + tal2;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked better only problem now is I get it so if (tal  == 56) is wrong, "use of unassigned local variable1 'tal1'

Comment: What is the initial value of tal1? You are trying to check the value before assigning it. You should set a default value before processig or accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Following code lines are wrong

```
if (tal1 == 56)
      Console.WriteLine(Addera(slinga, tal1));
    tal2--;
 else tal1 = 56;
```

You need to update it to

```
if (tal1 == 56){
     Console.WriteLine(Addera(slinga, tal1));
     tal2--;
}
 else {
    tal1 = 56;
}
```

Reason : You need `{ }` for multi-lined `if-else` conditions

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

> Both the then-statement and the else-statement can consist of a single statement or multiple statements that are enclosed in braces ({}). For a single statement, the braces are optional but recommended.

So you need `{ }` since it's multi-lined

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        if (tal1 == 56)
            Console.WriteLine(Addera(slinga, tal1));
            tal2--;
        else tal1 = 56;
```

to

```
        if (tal1 == 56)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Addera(slinga, tal1));
            tal2--;
        }
        else tal1 = 56;
```

The {} tells the compiler that the code between those brackets is part of the same logic branch.